# Make ImageButton fill parent height

Tags: android

I have this layout that I'm using/inflating in an ArrayAdapter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fileRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/uploadButton" 
        style="@style/fileUploadButton" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/upload_file"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon_upload"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/fileName"
        style="@style/fileNameButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/uploadButton"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want that ImageButton to be the same height as the Button. The Button can be of any height and I can't determine what that height is. The problem is the ImageButton is not filling the parent like I told it to.

The button's style is just the background color, so I didn't include it here for brevity.

Comment: your button doesn't have width, so it won't be displayed. It's width is 0dp

Comment: No, it's being displayed fine. :)

Comment: and how does it look like? With width 0 I can not image that it is visible...

Comment: I already said it's being displayed fine. It looks just like it's supposed to. The ImageButton next to it is too short though, that's what my question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your imagebutton

android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fileName"

Comment: Ah yes, I added `android:layout_alignTop` and `android:layout_alignBottom` to `fileName` and now the height is the same. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course. StackOverflow has a timer that you can't immediately mark it as accepted answer, so I had to wait 5 minutes.